# How to split a string with a word in php?

Tags: php, string

I have a string like

```
$str = "8 day tour details";
```

I need to get the details before days and after days. how can i split this sentence?

Comment: What? What is your question? What do you want to do?

Comment: `explode(' ', $str)` ???

Comment: First u can read u r question,what u have asked?

Comment: @ Let me see don't encourage this type of questions.

Comment: as mentioned @Letmesee, you can use explode() if the format will always be the same, otherwise you can use preg_split() which acts the same way except the fact it allows you to specify a regular expression as first parameter (usefull in the format you're expecting is a bit more complex)

Comment: @User I am not encouraging anyone. I tried to answer based on what I understood. BTW I have downvoted too 
:)

Comment: i need to split with the word "day"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a space after each word and i am assuming that sentence format will remain same. Your question is also a bit not clear so i am assuming what you have intended to ask.

```
$str = "8 day tour details";
$newstr = explode(" ",$str);
//$newstr[0] is the date 8 and $newstr[1] is the day
```

I hope this helps you.